# What is happening in this Python function?

Tags: python

```
def function(a):
    def f1(a, b): a[b] = (a.get(b) or 0) + 1; return a
    return map(lambda a: a[0], filter(lambda a: not a[1] == 1,
               reduce(f1, a, {}).items()))
```

I have tried printing the return value of this function.  Nothing prints when I assign a number to 'a', and if i assign a string to 'a', the function returns a list of random letters separated by commas.  Beyond this, I'm not sure what is happening or why those letters are being printed.  Was hoping someone smarter than me would be able to look at this and understand what's going on.

Also, is this considered a higher order function?

Comment: Please show the input you give and the output you get, and explain what output you expected instead.  When I run your function with a number input, I get an error, and when I run it with a string input, I just get a list with a single character.

Comment: Given a string, it seems to find the characters that occur more than once in that string, e.g. 'hello', or 'baadcc'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code looks intentionally obfuscated; hopefully it doesn't exist in production.  There's not a tax on the length of variable names or the number of lines.

That said, to understand it you just have to break it down a little.  We have:

```
return map(lambda a: a[0],               # extract the first element
        filter(lambda a: not a[1] == 1,  # take iff second element != 1
           reduce(f1, a, {}).items()     # reduce a using f1, then take items()
         )
    )
```

So, in other words, the result will be each key from the dictionary built by running `reduce(f1, a, {})` whose corresponding value is not `1`.

We can now consider what's actually going on here.

```
def f1(a, b):
    a[b] = (a.get(b) or 0) + 1
    return a
```

When passed as an argument to `reduce`, the first argument to `f1` will be the sequence which is being built, and the second argument will be the item which is being processed.

The sequence in question here is a dictionary (which you can tell from the argument to `reduce` as well as the use of `a.get` in `f1`).  With that in mind:

```
def f1(a, b):
    a[b] = (a.get(b) or 0) + 1  # increment value iff key present else value=1
    return a                    # return mutated sequence
```

The result of running `reduce(f1, 'some_string', {})` will therefore be a dictionary mapping characters to their frequency in the string.

The entire function thus returns all letters which occur more than once in the string.

---

The function in the question is obviously a contrived example; it is trivial to think of better ways to do this (hell, it's hard to think of *worse* ones).

One possible solution, although by no means the best, would be something like:

```
freqs = lambda s: [c for c in set(s) if s.count(c) > 1]
```

Alternatively, if you *really* love using `map` and `filter`, you could do:

```
freqs = lambda s: filter(lambda count: count > 1, map(s.count, set(s))
```

To be honest, though, this is one case where the python still of list comprehensions is *much* more readable; the above is as contrived and ugly as hell.

Comment: The code in the question may be ugly and unreadable, but one significant advantage it has over a `count`-based solution is linear runtime. In Python 2.7 or 3.x, to perform linear-time counting in an easily readable manner, the usual solution is to use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html): `[x for x, count in Counter(s).iteritems() if count > 1]`

Comment: That's a very good point, though I suspect doing so would amount to premature optimisation in the vast majority of cases (not that that makes it a bad idea, seeing how readable the `Counter` solution is).